# fstreams not deleted when delete is called in release mode

Tags: c++, memory-management, visual-studio-2013, fstream

I've run into an interesting problem that appears to be the result of visual studio 2013 not actually deleting fstreams when the delete operator is called for them. The code below is a simple program that, when compiled in visual studio 2013 with default debug mode, performs exactly as expected. When the code is compiled in release mode (with generate debug info turned on so that some debugging can be done) the delete operator behavior appears dependent on the contents of the delete operator. If the delete operator contains a cout, it is called immediately for portions of the memory allocated, if it doesn't contain a cout it isn't called at all until it runs the exit function in crtexe.c, and by the time it's called the foo mutex is in some invalid state, resulting in "Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEF6".

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include <fstream>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

mutex foo;

void* operator new(unsigned int size)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> memoryLock(foo);
    void* alloc = malloc(size);
    cout << "Allocating " << size << " bytes for " << alloc << endl;
    return alloc;
}

void* operator new[](unsigned int size)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> memoryLock(foo);
    void* alloc = malloc(size);
    cout << "Allocating " << size << " bytes for " << alloc << endl;
    return alloc;
}

void operator delete(void* ptr)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> memoryLock(foo);
    cout << "Deallocating " << ptr << endl;
    free(ptr);
}

void operator delete[](void* ptr)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> memoryLock(foo);
    cout << "Deallocating " << ptr << endl;
    free(ptr);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Address of Mutex: " << &foo << endl;
    cout << "Creating fstream... " << endl;
    fstream *blarg = new fstream("blarg.txt", ios::out);
    cout << "Deleteing fstream..." << endl;
    delete blarg;
    cout << "fstream deleted..." << endl;

    cout << "Exiting main..." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program outputs:

```
Address of Mutex: 00DD6658
Creating fstream...
Allocating 192 bytes for 003ABB00
Allocating 8 bytes for 00392A40
Deleteing fstream...
Deallocating 003ABB00
fstream deleted...
Exiting main...
```

and then crashes with the access violation.

If you set a breakpoint inside of the delete operator, you'll see the calls to it happen exactly as the output indicates. If you leave those breakpoints in, but comment out the cout line, then the debugged never hits the delete operator until it hits the exit function in crtexe.c.

The big issue is that for some reason, fstream (or at least not all of it's resources) is being deleted after it looks like other global resources have been destroyed, which means that fstream's dynamically allocated memory objects are calling the custom delete operator after resources that it uses are invalid.

I should be able to produce a workaround for my application, that's really not my concern at this point, I'm simply trying to understand the 'why' behind what's going on. Why would fstream's destructor and/or the freeing of it's memory be delayed? What, if anything, can be done to prevent this kind of behavior? Can I expect other classes to potentially produce this kind of behavior?

Comment: It would be useful to know the sequence of events taking place. It is possible that the mutex class is calling New and Delete in its constructor/destructor? That would cause problems here. I'd put some COUTs before every line of main and in your new and delete operators.

Comment: Found some interesting effects upon sprinkling the program with couts. Honestly, this gets weird. Editing the question with new information.

Comment: This information will at least get me to an understanding of how an object can be deleted without all of it's resources being deleted. Whatever the 8-byte allocation fstream makes is probably queued in some fashion to be deleted when the application exits. I'm still trying to wrap my head around why the debugger doesn't hit operator delete when the cout is removed. Is the operator actually not running, or is it something where the debugger just isn't getting the opportunity to see it?

Comment: Just tried adding in "this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5));" before exiting the thread, to see if maybe given time another thread would perform the deallocation of those 8 bytes, no such luck.

Comment: Try putting the cout's before the locks in the deallocator. I am more convinced than before that your mutex object is calling your delete operator.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I expect other classes to potentially produce this kind of behavior?

If the class has a custom `operator delete()` method, the global `operator delete()` function [is not called](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) at all.

In this case, it is possible the `fstream` has such a method, and your global function only gets called when the OS runtime is ready to deallocate the object.  It is also possible Visual C++ is doing something totally different.

Answer (score 0):

If this prints

```
class MyMutex : public mutex
{
public:
    virtual ~MuMutex () { cout << "Deleting Mutex" << endl ; }
} mutex ;
```

the problem is the mutex is calling your delete function and trying to lock itself.

Comment: No. Just because a destructor is called does not mean a delete operator is called. The delete operator is called only for dynamically allocated objects. If the mutex was using dynamically allocated memory, we'd see the new operator being called before the initial cout that outputs the memory address of the mutex. Additionally, the problem disappears if I allocate memory for something other than an fstream and then delete it. The problem is distinctly tied to the fstream, not the mutex.

Comment: I ran the code, however the only thing it shows is that, as I expected, the mutex is being deleted before the 8-byte data allocated by the fstream is being deleted.

If the mutex's destructor was calling delete, it would continue to call it regardless of whether an fstream was being allocated. Because the problem goes away when the fstream is removed, the problem cannot be blamed on the mutex which would continue to call delete during it's destructor.

Comment: Move your cout statements before the lock and you should see the problem.

Comment: You were correct, I found the problem. I found out that the delete operator is being called with the same memory address as the 8 bytes of memory that are allocated by the fstream and then crashing when it attempts to lock the mutex... which means that some of the resources of the fstream are surviving the deletion of the fstream and are only being deleted after the mutex has been deconstructed.